# Create Multiple Folders Within One Directory

Tags: ruby, fileutils

I am trying to build a simple File Structure with as little LOC as possible,
I understand that `FileUtils.mkdir_p './this/that/the/other'` makes a path. Is there anything in Ruby that makes multiple folders within one directory like `FileUtils.mkdir_p './this/{that, foo, bar}/the/other`(This does not work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%w(that foo bar).each{|dir| FileUtils.mkdir_p( "./this/#{dir}/the/other")}
```

Note the double quotes, they allow for string interpolation (the execution of code within a string).

Comment: Awesome! This is the answer that I was looking for. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
%w[this that next].each{|dir| Dir.mkdir "/path/to/somewhere/#{dir}"}
```

This will create `/path/to/somewhere/this`, `/path/to/somewhere/that`, `/path/to/somewhere/next` folders.

By the way, you can create only one folder at a time. i.e. you have to create one folder `./foo`, then `./foo/bar`, then `./foo/bar/next`

It has nothing to do with ruby, it is common way of OS work

Comment: OP uses `mkdir_p`, which certainly [creates a directory and all of its parent directories](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p).